# Get only datetime from list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

```
lst = ['Last Modified (GMT)', 'Size', '26-Mar-2022 09:17', '',
       '22-Mar-2022 17:30', '', '31-Jan-2022 18:44', '',
       '26-Mar-2022 09:17', '30.8 MB']
```

How to get only dates from this list of strings in python?

Output should be - 26-Mar-2022 09:17
22-Mar-2022 17:30
31-Jan-2022 18:44
26-Mar-2022 09:17

Comment: There are a lot of details missing from your question: Do you want to parse the strings as datetime objects for other uses? Or do you want to only print out the strings? What is the pattern in the list for strings that are datetimes?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged it pandas, you could use `pandas.to_datetime` method:

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.to_datetime(lst, errors='coerce').dropna().strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['26-Mar-2022 09:17', '22-Mar-2022 17:30', '31-Jan-2022 18:44', '26-Mar-2022 09:17']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from datetime import datetime

out = []
for i in lst:
    try:
        out.append(datetime.strptime(i, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M'))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 26, 9, 17),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 22, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 18, 44),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 26, 9, 17)]
```

Maybe you have to define the `locale` to match the '%b':

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = []
for string in list:
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(string, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')
        dates.append(date)
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(dates)
```

If you need a purely pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use itemgetter if I am understanding your request.

```
from operator import itemgetter

li = ['Last Modified (GMT)', 'Size', '26-Mar-2022 09:17', '', '22-Mar-2022 17:30', '', '31-Jan-2022 18:44', '', '26-Mar-2022 09:17', '30.8 MB']

print(*itemgetter(2, 4, 6, 8)(li))
```